# Google Weather API Returned Weather Images

Tags: ios

I am consuming the Google Weather API in my mobile application

http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/02/08/googles-secret-weather-api/

Everything works as expected. I get the temp in Fahrenheit and everything and also the image. But in the evening time around 7-8 PM it still returns the same sunny image. Is there any other service which changes the condition image for the night time?

Comment: By the way, was that you who did some cocos2d podcasts with Steffen Itterheim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the blog post you mentioned, it seems that you could easily grab the appropriate image based on the weather conditions. Nobody says you need to trust the XML response for that image.

Comment: yeah I can grab any image! I might just use some custom image or something since Google images are small icons and not full size images. Thanks!